# Problem with interpolation of 3D points in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, 3d, interpolation

I have a sample of 3D points (x,y,z) with tepmerature attribute. I can import my data as a 3D vector map. I want to create a volume of voxels by using v.vol.rst. When I use this module, this error happens 
WARNING: strip exists with insufficient data
Processing all selected output files will require 0 bytes of disk space for temp files

can somebody help me how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Regions settings?? g.region vect=<vector points map>

Comment: yes. i set the extent of region based on input 3D vector points.

Comment: The "WARNING" part usually means that there are no points in part of the region. It should *not* cause the interpolation to fail. But the "require 0 bytes" means that something else is wrong. Perhaps a small sample of your data would help to find what the problem is?

Comment: Thanks Micha for the reply. Here is a sample of my data:

Comment: 320554.395    5814603.902    45.169    24.60

Comment: 320558.868 5814603.368 45.009  24.30

Comment: 320558.868 5814603.368 45.009  24.30

Comment: 320555.357 5814601.188 45.124  24.00

Comment: 320550.868  5814601.691           45.394                    24.30

Comment: The first three values are x,y,z respectively and the last one shows the temperature in each point

Comment: OK, and have you imported the x,y,z,t values into a GRASS 3d vector?

Answer (score 3):

When I mentioned a "small sample" I didn't mean that small ;-)
Anyway, I copied the 5 points into a text file, made it "comma-separated" and improted into GRASS with:

```
v.in.ascii -z in=temp_pts.txt out=temp_pts fs=, columns="X double precision, Y double precision, Z double precision, T double precision" z=3
```

I set the region to the imported vector map, with a very small resolution (only so few points):

```
g.region vect=temp_pts res=0.1 -p3
```

Then I could run the following to get a 3D raster:

```
v.vol.rst --o in=temp_pts wcol=T elev=temp_interp npmin=4 dmin=0
```

The dmin and npmin are artifically small to allow for the tiny set of points, but it seems to work...